# Examples of Toronto spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

I remember $\dagger$ the notion of **cardinality** (a bijection), and the definitions of  **homeomorphism** and **Hausdorff space** (separation axiom $T_2$). I would like to know if **there exists examples of Toronto spaces**, I say 
explicitly an example of a Toronto space that you can show us. Or it is theopen question?

> **Question.** Can you provide us a space $X$ endowed with a topology $T_X$ being $(X, T_X)$ an example of **Toronto space**?

Then with the definition of to be a [Toronto space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_space) provide us by **Wikipedia** please show us your example. If there are no interesting examples tell us why, and if it is possible the reasoning by it is difficult find/build examples of Toronto spaces. **Many thanks.**

---

$\dagger$ In the past I've studied topology, and I am interested to try refresh some concepts in topology with questions. Feel free to edit this (my first post about topology) to improve notation, grammar...

Comment: Obviously any finite or discrete space is a Toronto space. The Wikipedia article gives a complete list of countable Toronto spaces; it implies that there are no countable Hausdorff Toronto spaces other than the discrete ones. It seems that it is an open problem to find a non-discrete uncountable Hausdorff Toronto space. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24144/is-there-an-uncountable-non-discrete-hausdorff-toronto-space

Comment: Very thanks much @arkeet my problems is that I did not understand well the article from Wikipedia, and I didn't see your first claim, now I try understand your words. Now I am reading your comment.

Comment: Now I believe that I understand your first claim: since bijections between subspaces $Y\subseteq X$ with same cardinality than $X$ are homeomorphims? Isn't it? Thanks @arkeet

Comment: Right, any two discrete spaces of the same cardinality are homeomorphic (for any map between them is continuous). The finite case is trivial, as finite sets contain no proper subsets of the same cardinality.